# How to compute autocorrelation function in R

Tags: r

I'd like to know the best way to compute autocorrelation function as defined below.

For i=1,2,... I would like to compute the i-th autocorrelation function acf.
This is the sum, from k = 1 to n-i, of +1 if v(k) = v(k+i) or -1 if v(k) is different from v(k+i), where n is the length of a vector.

For example:

```
if v<-c(0,1,1,0,0) and i = 2.  Then
acf(v) = (-1) + (-1) + (-1)  = -3
```

Thanks!

Comment: Autocorrelation values are between -1 and +1.

Answer (score 1):

What about using R-help? There you should have found the `acf` function.

```
v = c(1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1)
acf(v,plot=F) -> acf_v
acf_v[2]
```

Comment: Did you check the result?

Comment: Thanks but it is not my defined ACF. Please have a look at the example given in my posting. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I created a function to do to it but still looking for a short and efficient way to do it.

Here is the function:

```
> v<-c(0,1,1,1,0,1,1)
> acf_bit <-function(vec,lag) {
+   m<-length(vec)
+   t<-0
+   for (k in 1:(m-lag)) {
+     if (v[k]==v[k+lag]) {t<-t+1}
+     else {t<-t-1}
+   }
+   return(t)
+ }
> acf_bit(v,2)
[1] -1
```